# How can I retrieve the time used and relative MIP gap after optimizing with GLPK in Pyomo?

Tags: pyomo, glpk

I am using a concrete model with Pyomo (using GLPK) where two optimizations are run for each day of the year, but during test runs (just a couple of days) the MIP gap is sometimes very high (around 8%) after the time limit. I wish to store (in a dataframe) the time used for each optimization and the MIP gap that was reached, so I can get an idea of a) how long does the average optimization take, and b) how close the results are to optimality. How can I retrieve this data? I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

The code and the data used are too long to share, but this is how I am calling the solver and giving a time limit and gap criteria:

```
model = create_model(parameters_a, parameters_b)
solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
solver.options["mipgap"] = 0.01
solver.options["tmlim"] = 1000
solver.solve(model, tee=True, symbolic_solver_labels=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has various utilities for timing, which may be useful. You can also check the contents of the return object from the `solve()` call:

```
import time
start = time.time()

results = solver.solve(model, tee=True)
print(results)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```